# ¿Como hacer que se graben los saltos de linea de un html con fstream? c++

Tags: html, c++, dev-c++, fstream

estoy haciendo un ejercicio para guardar archivos en formato HTML con C++.
Mi problema es que no guarda los saltos de linea y se muestra todo de corrido al momento de abrir el archivo, ya intenté de varias formas pero sigo sin poder lograrlo, espero que me puedan ayudar.

```
/*Este es el ejemplo para que vean como pondriamos 
hacer lo del guardado en html*/

#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void escribir();

int main(){
    escribir();
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
} 

void escribir(){ //Aqui es donde comienza como tal este pedo
    ofstream archivo; //Este es el comando para hacer el archivo y "archivo" es el nombre de la variable, se puede poner el nombre que sea
    
    archivo.open("Pagina.html",ios::out); //Esto  hace que se cree el archivo
    
    if(archivo.fail()){ //Si a ocurrido algun error
        cout<<"No se pudo crear el archivo, vuelva a intentarlo";
        exit(1);
    }
    
    archivo<<"Aqui va todo lo que queremos que se guarde \r\nIncluso en varios parrafos";
    archivo<<"\r\nAdemas de que se pueden usar varias lineas";

    printf("Su pagina se ha generado exitosamente\n");
    
    archivo.close(); //Con esto se cierra el archivo
}
```

Comment: Lo que estás guardando no es código HTML. ¿Es este un ejemplo real? ¿Cómo estás "abriendo el archivo" para ver el contenido? ¿Con un editor de texto o con el navegador?

Answer (score 1):

En Mac y Linux se utiliza como fin de línea el caracter *Line Feed* (LF o `'\n'`), en Windows, en cambio se emplea la secuencia *Carriage Return* + *Line Feed* (CRLF o `"\r\n"`).

Si editas el archivo con el block de notas de Windows, al tratarse de un visor muy básico y enfocado a su uso en Windows, verás que aparece todo en una misma línea. El motivo es que no estás usando CRLF sino únicamente LF.

Sin embargo, si optas por abrir el archivo con otras herramientas (wordpad, notepad++, ...), al ser editores más potentes, detectarán que tu archivo no usa CRLF sino únicamente LF y usarán esta secuencia para separar las líneas.

Sin embargo, si editas el archivo en MAC o Linux, da igual el editor, verás que las líneas aparecen bien definidas.

Tu problema, por tanto, es relativo. No puedes disponer un mecanismo que funcione en todas las plataformas a la vez. Ahora bien, si te estás limitando a trabajar en Windows entonces sería recomendable que te adaptases a sus requisots, en este caso CRLF en vez de simplemente LF

Comment: Una duda, si usas `std::endl`, ¿no te abstrae de ese problema? En función de donde compiles incluirá los caracteres que le hagan falta. ¿No es así?

Comment: @SuperG280 `std::endl` introducirá `\r\n` en windows y `\n` en Linux y Mac. Sin embargo, `std::endl` tiene otros efectos colaterales, como por ejemplo que vacía el buffer de salida (se vuelca el buffer a la pantalla, al archivo ... lo que toque). Esta operación es costosa, por lo que conviene no realizarla alegremente en todos los saltos de línea (pueden darse problemas de rendimiento)

Answer (score 0):

El ejemplo que tu das no reproduce el problema, al abrir el archivo en windows me sale el texto que toca, y al abrirlo en linux me sale con unos `^M` antes de el salto de linea pero el salto de linea existe.

Ahora, ya que nos falta información, lo mas que puedo suponer es que lo estas abriendo en el navegador. Para resolverlo te dejo el siguiente trozo de html:

```html
a
a
a
a
a
a

<hr/>

a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>

<hr/>

<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
```